# MS Access VBA How to delete a row in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have used the below code to open an Excel file in MS Access 2003. 
I would like to delete row 2 or A2:K2.

```
            Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
            Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

            xlApp.Visible = True

            xlApp.Workbooks.Open "QuotebyItem.xls", True, False
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Dim wb as Excel.Workbook
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application             

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")              
xlApp.Visible = True 

Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("QuotebyItem.xls", True, False)
wb.Sheets(1).Rows(2).Delete
```

...assuming your file has only one sheet: if there might be multiple and you need to address only one of them:

```
wb.Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(2).Delete
```

Comment: Is it possible delete rows from vba also if some fields are protected?

Comment: Why not try and see?  I guess it would depend on the level of protection, so it's difficult to say yes or no in general.