# MS Access VBA How to I supress the "Do you want to save changes" dialog for excel row deletes?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Similar to a question in
[MS Access VBA How to delete a row in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069119/ms-access-vba-how-to-delete-a-row-in-excel)

However, the problem is Excel asks for "Do you want to save the changes you made to ...?" 
Is there a way to force the saving of changes and disable any message box? I try DoCmd.SetWarnings False, but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add the following code to `ThisWorkbook`

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

If you're running vba in Access and accessing an Excel object, just save the workbook (e.g. `xlApp.ThisWorkbook.Save`) in your code before closing

Comment: You can suppress warning messages using Application.DisplayAlerts = False, possibly using xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False from Access, but you shouldn't need to do this if the workbook has been saved anyway.

Comment: @GrahamAnderson At first i thought that too, but in excel, using `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` won't work if you make new edits to a workbook and then close it without saving. *I think* it's because Excel sets `DisplayAlerts` to true after a macro runs, and since the `Workbook_BeforeClose` completes without saving (and then auto-sets displayAlerts back to true) you are prompted with the alert to save changes

Comment: That depends on how you do it, you can close a workbook whilst running a macro with the DisplayAlerts off and therefore not get a warning. Typically you would do this when a macro in one book opens and closes other workbooks. Of course the `workbook.close` method has an option for closing without saving and sends no message when you set the save option to false.